# Share a PDF file but keep the comments private

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-comments

I would like to share ~50 pdf files with my collaborator, but not the private comments I have on those files. I wonder if this is possible on Google drive.

The easiest solution will be keeping two copies for each file: (1) one shared with the collaborator without any comments and (2) other not shared copy with private comments.

However, for ~50 files, this way will most probably lead to a complicated system wherein I would have to keep track of two files and their two links (URLs) for each file at the same time.

I wonder if there is any solution for this.

I wish there was a way to control the visibility of the comments on PDFs, or the ability to create a symbolic link ("Add a shortcut on Drive" option) that does not reveal comments on the pdf.

Comment: Removed the Google Apps Script tag as this app was not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to prevent that editors changes the sharing settings and that viewers copy download or print a shared file, it's not possible to keep the comments "private" when sharing a file in Google Drive.

Please submit your feedback directly to Google. One way to do this is from the Google Drive Help.

Resources

- [Restrict sharing options on Drive files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308868?hl=en)